# Searching for “package-name” failed in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

I've tried to install a package in Atom but the problem is that it returned me just this message "Searching for “*package-name*” failed.".

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem and worked for me. Follow the below steps:

1- Disable your device proxy

2- if still doesn't work, disable your firewall, restart the program and make an another effort